# Why do some memories have a closer 'feeling' in time than others?

Tags: memory

There are some memories in my head which seems to have occured much more far away than it actually has happend, that is there is a feeling of disconnect between the actual timeline of events which has happend in my life vs my memories. Supposing that this happens to 'other' people too, why does this happen?

By the way , I have seen this [thread](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/why-do-some-memories-stick-out-more-than-others) but it's more about the intensity of the memory rather than how the memories fit into the timeline of our mind vs the timeline of the realworld.

Comment: I've looked a bit into false memories/hearing, so my best answer to this would be that it has to do with emotional arousal and recency since the memory was last recalled. I don't think I've seen this exact question answered using neurological studies, but I have not really looked for a study addressing that specifically. So I'd say this could be a really interesting research project! I think the consensus is that emotional arousal leads to higher susceptibility to false memory because it would be more frequently recalled and therefore subject to alteration. Studying reported recall of dates an